# Mount storage when running an Azure Function locally

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I understood that it is now possible to mount storage such as Azure Files when running an Azure Function.

How can I do it when I execute the Function locally? I probably have to add some entries to `local.settings.json`? Or is this even possible at all?

(I'm using Python in the function but that probably doesn't affect the answer. Or does it?)

Comment: Can you provide some more details around your requirement? The file local.settings.json stores app settings, connection strings, and settings for Azure Functions Core Tools. Settings in the local.settings.json file are only used by Functions tools when running locally.

Comment: are you able to mount storage using Azure function? I am trying to achieve using c# with linux system but I am not able to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your real question is how to mount Azure Storage to your local machine to be used as same as local filesystem inside Azure Function locally, but I don't know what service of Azure Storage you want to mount on local.

As I known, there are two ways to mount Azure Storage to local filesystem.

1. To mount an Azure file share with [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows), [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) or [MacOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-mac) via SMB 3.0 protocol. It's a cross-platform solution.
2. To mount a container of Azure Blob Storage with Linux only via a tool named `blobfuse` which use `libfuse` to communicate with Linux FUSE kernel module. You can refer to its GitHub repo [`Azure/azure-storage-fuse`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse) to know it in details.

No matter which one above you used, you can directly access the file of Azure Storage on Azure Function locally, such as use `os.open` in Python.